# Add Cancel Button to UIKeyboard

Tags: ios, swift3, uikeyboard

I want to add a cancel button to hide the keyboard if the user wants to. I cant find any solution for swift 3.

Comment: Where do you want to add the button?

Comment: on the keyboard, or where the done button appear (which is on the top of the keyboard)

Comment: The available return key  types are [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uireturnkeytype?language=objc).there is no cancel return key type

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation of a `UITextField`'s `inputAccessoryView`: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield/1619627-inputaccessoryview

> Assigning a view to this property causes that view to be displayed above the standard system keyboard (or above the custom input view if one is provided) when the text field becomes the first responder. For example, you could use this property to attach a custom toolbar to the keyboard.

I recommend to assign a `UIToolbar` that contains your cancel button to the `inputAccessoryView` of the `UITextField` that needs the cancel button. Then hook up an action to the button that resigns the first responder from the `UITextField`.